# can a VirtualBox VM run on different hardware?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have created a VM using VirtualBox on 'A' hardware configuration.
Can I expect correct working of this VM if I copy the VM hard drive image and use it on a different hardware configuration 'B'?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yup. It'll be fine. Regardless of where installed, virtualbox will always present the same virtual devices.

Comment: ic...thanks.. so will check this behaviour out on monday at office.. :) btw that was a quick response!!

Comment: yup it did work flawlessly... and the os reports all upgraded hardware too like more ram and more cpu juice..! on company's dell workstations :)

Answer (score 1):

The only time you might have trouble is if you "suspend" execution instead of stopping or shutting down the virtual machine. Otherwise you should be fine, that's one of the advantages of virtual machines.

Answer (score 1):

The guest HD image (vdi) will certainly work straight off. The VM config XML file doesn't necessary transfer cleanly between hosts running different OSes, but then it's pretty trivial to create a new virtual machine using the old vdi in that case.