# VM portability between VirtualBox versions (2.2.4/4.x)

Tags: virtualbox, upgrade, migration, export, import

I know that [a VirtualBox VM can run on different hardware](https://superuser.com/questions/99540/can-a-VirtualBox-VM-run-on-different-hardware), but this doesn't help me because in my case the platform doesn't change (Linux). I'd rather like to upgrade VirtualBox from 2.2.4 to 4.x.

Will the VM start again (if that matters, WindowsXP)?

**-- UPDATE**

VM **are** easily portable from platform to platform using [Import/Export capability](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html#ovf) (introduced in VirtualBox 2.2). Totally painless and works like a charm (**though Windows needs to be reactivated**, at least for me).

Answer (score 5):

You should be fine. Any upgrade will keep the existing VMs. It is generally suggested that you backup your VMs for any upgrade though.

Comment: @Guandalino How'd the upgrade work out?

Comment: question updated with the solution I was looking for. Thanks for your input.